# Buttons not working after AJAX, does not get parameters to the controllers

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am pretty new to AJAX. I understand that after a new element is added there are no events attached to the new elements.

What I have is a form for creating a business, it opens a modal, we fill the fields and then it adds it via AJAX and then adds a row to the data table. 
This row has the name of the user but when this is done, my button does not take the parameter name and add image requires the name of the business to be able to work.

```js
$("#formCreateBusiness").submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var myformdata = $("#formCreateBusiness").serialize();

    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
    }

    $.post("/Administration/Admin/CreateBusiness", myformdata)
        .done(function (dataResponse) {
            toastr.success("Created business succesfully");
            $("#CreateBusinessModal").modal('hide');

            var buttons = <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" 
    href="/Administration/Admin/AllLogbooksForBusiness/${dataResponse.name}">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
            Manage Logbooks
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-top:5%"

    href="/Administration/Admin/AddImageToBusiness/${dataResponse.name}">
            <i class="fas fa-images"></i>
            Add Image
        </a>`;

            $('#table').DataTable().row.add([dataResponse.name, dataResponse.location, dataResponse.description, buttons]).draw();

        }).fail(function (dataResponse) {
            toastr.error(dataResponse.responseJSON.message);
        });
});
```

Comment: There is a missing ` in your `var buttons`. It should be var buttons = `

Comment: Thank you! Well spotted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing `'` in your code. Add `'` after `var buttons =` to fix the syntax.

Your code is:

```js
 var buttons = <a ...
```

just change it to this:

```js
var buttons = '<a ...

...</a>';
```

It's recommended to use an IDE or proper code editor, because using one will highlight syntax errors like these for you in the future.